# so I have a USB-C DAC, can I use USBC-to-USBA adapter?

Tags: usb, dac

As above.

The only USB-C ports I have are both thunderbolt ports but I want to use both for extra displays. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: just get a usb-A to usb-C cable. It's not likely that the DAC will require anything more than usb-2 speeds.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR - Yes

*Most* of these USB adaptors are simply connectors wired together - no electronics. This means that there is nothing that will change or impede data in any way.

There are a few cases where the adaptor may only have the data channels wired and won't support USB power delivery, or where they have some sort of protection circuitry to prevent damage from/to external USB devices, and these *might* affect the data transfer but they are getting less and less common.